# Раскрытие typing.TypeVarTuple с "шаблонном"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.11, typing

Как мне получить тип `tuple[A[int], A[int]]` для `b.b` как в коде для c++?

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
Ts = typing.TypeVarTuple('Ts')

class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    a: T

class B(typing.Generic[*Ts]):
    b: tuple[*A[Ts]] # <<< Ошибка Pylance: TypeVarTuple not allowed in this context

b: B[int, int] = B()
typing.reveal_type(b.b) # выводит не правильный тип: tuple[A[*tuple[int, int]]]
# Ожидалось tuple[A[int], A[int]]
```

Код c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T a;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct B {
    std::tuple<A<Ts>...> b;
};

int main() {
    B<int, int> b;
    std::cout << typeid(b.b).name() << std::endl;
    // std::__1::tuple<A<int>, A<int>>
    return 0;
}
```

Я пробовал `tuple[*(A[T1] for T1 in Ts)]`, но Pylance игнорирует это и ругается вообще на квадратную скобку.

Comment: Укажите как поле b инициализируете, и точную версию интерпретатора. У меня ваш код на Python 3.11.4 без инициализации b.b выводит `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'b'`, а с инициализацией `Runtime type is 'tuple'` (не `tuple[A[*tuple[int, int]]]`)

Comment: @insolor Этот код предполагалось должен работать для линтера (в моем случае Pylance, но можно другой), `typing.reveal_type(b.b)` в отладку выводит тип как info

Answer (score 0):

Я не силен в такой сложной типизации и не знаю cpp )
Но получилось сделать так, чтобы тип был `tuple[A[int], A[int]]` для `b.b`. Надеюсь будет полезно)

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
Ts = typing.TypeVarTuple('Ts')

class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    a: T

class B(typing.Generic[*Ts, T]):
    b: tuple[A[T], A[T]]

b: B[int, int] = B()
typing.reveal_type(b.b)
```

Comment: Это только для случая (int, int) будет работать)) А если нужно будет далее другое количество, то все) Я решил переделать половину кода и выкинуть эту часть заменив тяжелой библиотекой, но все же было интересно есть ли ответ на эту проблему

Comment: Вообще вроде согласно PEP646 https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#splitting-arbitrary-length-tuples для этой цели можно использовать многоточие -

Comment: Не понимаю как в данном случае можно использовать многоточие, можно пример?